# getopt not recognizing multiple command line flags in c

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm in the process of learning C, and I am trying to get command line flags using getopt() to work. My problem is that it will only recognize the first command flag as a flag, and considers any others as regular command line arguments. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *delivery = "";
    int thick = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
            case 'd':
                delivery = optarg;
                break;
            case 't':
                thick = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg);
                return 1;
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
    }
    if(thick) {
        puts("Thick crust.");
    }
    if (delivery[0]) {
        printf("To be delivered %s.\n", delivery);
    }
        puts("Ingredients:");
        for(count = 0; count < argc; count++) {
            if (!strstr(argv[count], "./")) {
                puts(argv[count]);
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

When I do one flag or no flags it works completely fine:

```
$ ./order_pizza Anchovies
Ingredients:
Anchovies

$ ./order_pizza Anchovies Pineapple
Ingredients:
Anchovies
Pineapple

$ ./order_pizza -d now Anchovies Pineapple
To be delivered now.
Ingredients:
Anchovies
Pineapple

$ ./order_pizza -t Anchovies Pineapple
Thick crust.
Ingredients:
Anchovies
Pineapple
```

However, when I do more than one flag:

```
$ ./order_pizza -d now -t Anchovies Pineapple
To be delivered now.
Ingredients:
-t
Anchovies
Pineapple

$ ./order_pizza -t -d now Anchovies Pineapple
Thick crust.
Ingredients:
-d
now
Anchovies
Pineapple
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, as from my searching no one seems to be having the same issue. I'm on Windows 7 using cygwin and compiling using the following line:

```
$ gcc order_pizza.c -o order_pizza
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify `argc` and `argv` inside of the `while` loop where you call `getopt`.  It uses those variables to do its magic, so changing them messes it up.

So instead of this:

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
    ...
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
}
```

Do this:

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
    ...
    }
}
argc -= optind;
argv += optind;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so dumb, this code was part of a "fill in the blank" exercise in the book I'm using, and I miss copied some of the code (they don't use brackets everywhere I like to, so when I added some brackets I put the ending bracket in the wrong spot). Moving the bracket fixed everything!